# Excel now() shouldn't update existing timestamp

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel formula `=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A2)), TEXT(NOW(), "mm/dd/yyyy HH:ss"),"")`

My Problem is: Of course, everytime I open this sheet it updates the cell value associated with most recent timestamp. I do not want this timestamp to change if it already existed.

What I want is somehow: if A2 is not blank and wasn't updated recently then dont update the timestamp else update.

I am looking for an inline function if possible.

Thanks

Comment: I do not think that you can do this with Excel forumlas in a single cell.  You could probably do it with multiple cells.  You could also do it with VBA triggering on change events, but that's pretty messy and complex.

Comment: Now I am pretty sure that even with multiple cells, it cannot be done with excel formulas alone.  VBA Events are the only way that it can be done (or else with VSTO Events).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a VBA macro:

1. Open VBA editor (Tools > Macro > Visual Basic Editor)
2. On the left, right-click Sheet1 and select View Code
3. Copy the following into the editor:

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row = 2 Then
    If Target.Value = "" Then
      Cells(2, 2).Value = ""
    Else
      Cells(2, 2).Value = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

---

If you write something into cell A2, then a timestamp will be written into cell B2, and when you delete A2, B2 will also be deleted. The timestamp won't be automatically updated.

Comment: +1:  You could also store the change-date into a VBA public or module variable and the write a VBA function to return it that can be called from Excel formulas (this would remove the code dependency on the output cell).

Comment: Thanks guys...I was searching if I could find a way somehow to fix it in formula....apparently, that is not possible from what I've looked up.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to record the time of edit in a range of cells (say A9:C20 and D11:E12) if any of the cell in (A2:C2 or E3:F4) is edited.

You can do this:

Right-click the sheet tab and select 'View code' and paste the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("A2:C2,E3:F4")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Range("A9:C20,D11:E12").Value = Now()
Range("A9:C20,D11:E12").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
End Sub
```

The timestamp will not be autoupdated unless any of (A2:C2 or E3:F4) is edited again.

Answer (score 2):

File > Options > Formulas > Check Manual Calculations > Uncheck 'Recalculate workbook before saving'.
If needed also check enable iterative and set max iterations to 1 as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the default iteration to `1`, so it recalculates one time before it stops.

Go to this:

1. Office button
2. Excel Options
3. Formulas
4. Iteration

Answer (score -1):

OK - so I realize this thread is ancient.
However, I ran across an excel formulaic approach to this that I thought I'd share:

Cell A1 = cell with Data Validation list of Complete,Incomplete
Cell A2 = IF(A1="Complete",IF(A2="",NOW(),A2),"")

Iteration Needs to be turned on - so be thoughtful about other potential circular references - but this will return a blank cell until you flip A1 to "Complete."  Once you've done that - it will update A2.  A2 will then stay in that state as long as you don't change the status of A1.

You can also change the trigger to other fields etc, in my case, I keep it in incomplete until the form is ready, then flip it to Complete and the time stamp sticks.