# Timestamp in Appscript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a timestamp within Google Sheets in Appscript. Whenever a cell in ColumnA is updated, I want the current date/time placed in ColumnB.

Tried using now() function but that updated all cells.

Same question as this post below but in Appscript not VBA:
[Excel now() shouldn't update existing timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804975/excel-now-shouldnt-update-existing-timestamp)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
function fillFormulae(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
  var lastUsedRow = sheets.getLastRow();

  for (j=0; j < lastUsedRow - 2; j ++ ){
    var cell = sheets.getRange(3+j, 2);
    if (cell.getValue() == '') {
      cell.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "PST", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If ColA is the column you are editing, and ColB is where you want the date to be posted try this:

```
function onEdit({ source }) {
    const sheet = source.getActiveSheet();
  
    if (sheet.getName() == "Sheet1") {
      const activeRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
      const editColumn = activeRange.getColumn();
      const rowIndex = activeRange.getRowIndex();
      const headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
      const editedCol = headers[0].indexOf("Edited") + 1;
      const dateCol = headers[0].indexOf("Date") + 1;
  
      if (dateCol > 0 && rowIndex > 1 && editColumn == editedCol) {
        sheet
          .getRange(rowIndex, dateCol)
          .setValue(
            Utilities.formatDate(
              new Date(),
              SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),
              "dd/MM/yyyy @ HH:mm"
            )
          );
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
    }
  }
```

Just make sure to set the Trigger up as 'onEdit'.

This will result in something like

```
+--------------+--------------------+
|      A       |         B          |
+--------------+--------------------+
| Test         | 14/01/2022 @ 02:15 |
| Tested Again | 14/01/2022 @ 02:25 |
+--------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: how could I do If I want to use other column as trigger?